# Unable to integration test with web api use Openiddict

Tags: asp.net-core, testing, integration-testing, .net-5, openiddict

[MS Docs mock-authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#mock-authentication)

Please take a look at above link.
If I use below code,will throw exception said duplicate scheme.

```
var scheme=＂OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme＂;

services.AddAuthentication(scheme)
.AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, TestAuthHandler>(
scheme, options => {});
```

So I don't know how to add the mock handler to the scheme which was added by openiddict or remove the openiddict service when running the test.